# Appending an element of an array to the array itself

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am working with a small array, in the form of an int pointer. For the sake of example, the array has 3 elements, [0, 1, 2].

I want to, based on a check, take an element with index i and move it to the back of the array. If the index is 0, the array should be reordered [1, 2, 0]. Then, next time I do it, if the index is 1, it should be reordered [1, 0, 2].

The check I am using is, if the current value at index i is equal to a particular value of an element of a struct. The code of the struct is as follows:

```
struct          Process {
    int id;
    int cpu;
    int io;
    int arrival;
};
```

My array i am working on is called queue. This is my current attempt at the reorder:

```
for (int q = 0; q < n; q++) {
    if (queue[q] == p[i].id) {
        while (q++ < n)
            queue[q] = queue[q + 1];
        queue[n - 1] = p[i].id;
        break;
    }
}
```

So, I am checking if the element of queue is equal to the id of an instance of Process (p[] is a list of processes of type Process). If it is, I want to shift every element back by 1, then set the last element equal to the id of that Process instance that I used for the check. The while loop was previously (with n = total number of processes and thus total number of elements of queue):

```
for (int r = q + 1; r < n; r++) {}
```

but I believe both have the same effect and neither are working as I think they should.

It is worth mentioning that the elements of queue are set based off of the id's of elements in p[] as those elements are initialized, so p[i].id should always be found in queue.

Comment: You're accessing outside the array on the last iteration. You're testing the old value of `q` to see if it's in bounds, then incrementing it with `++`.

Comment: Also, on the 2nd to last iteration, `queue[q+1]` is outside the array.

Comment: I noticed that just after I posted. Wouldn't it only try to access outside the array on the last iteration of the while loop?  On the second to last iteration doesn't q = n - 2? Either way, I'm curious as to why this did not segfault.

Comment: Because you're using post-increment, not pre-increment. `q++ < n` compares the current value of `q` to `n`, sees that it's in range, then increments it and goes into the loop body. So then `q = n` on the last iteration.

Comment: Changing it to `while (++q < n) {queue[q - 1] = queue[q];} ` seems to have done the trick!